# Mysql : how to add a where clause superior on text

Tags: mysql

I want to add a superior on where clause but my row is a text not an int.

For instance :
SELECT * FROM table WHERE row>'20'
I've got results including 10 / 15 / 200.

Do you have any solution because i can't change row's type.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data, desired results, and include the table structure.

Comment: Try it after removing quotes `'`

Answer (score 0):

Try it after removing quotes `'`.